# To pi or not to pi?

Tags: renormalization, superconductivity

Some research articles normalize superconductor Green's function to satisfy  this condition $G^2=1$. Others use a different condition $G^2=-\pi^2$. Why is there a difference? What is the purpose of normalization of the Green's function?

Examples of articles:

- [To $\pi$](http://www.phys.ens.fr/~cottet/GeneralBCs.pdf)
- [Not To $\pi$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9812297)

Comment: Did you mean $G^2 = -\pi^2$? So $G$ is imaginary?

Comment: I provided the links and yes, $G$  has imaginary parts.